# JSONExeption: No value for items

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I'm trying to parse some JSON in my Android application. A JSONObject is returned and in that JSONObject there's a JSONArray. But my problem is: in some way Android does not recognize the array in the JSONObject.

This is my Android code:

```
JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();   
JSONObject json = jp.getList(id,code);
Log.v("json: ", json.getString("tag"));
JSONArray jarr = json.getJSONArray("items");
for (int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); i++) {
 JSONObject jobj = jarr.getJSONObject(i);  
 list.add(jobj.getString("title"));
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

My JSON is OK, because this `Log.v("json: ", json.getString("tag"));` just works fine.
this is my JSON:

```
{
 tag: "getlist",
 status: 1,
 success: "false",
 items: [
  {
   id: "1",
   owner: "1",
   datecreated: "2013-10-12 20:05:00",
   version: "1",
   title: "asdfjkl",
   subject: "Wiskunde D"
  },
  {
   id: "2",
   owner: "1",
   datecreated: "2013-10-28 05:32:09",
   version: "1",
   title: "asdfjkl",
   subject: "Nederlands"
  }
 ]
}
```

And finnaly my LogCat:

```
04-05 22:23:39.082: D/Http Response:(31845): org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost@65684f78
04-05 22:23:39.082: V/json:(31845): getlist
04-05 22:23:39.082: W/System.err(31845): org.json.JSONException: No value for items
04-05 22:23:39.092: W/System.err(31845):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
04-05 22:23:39.092: W/System.err(31845):    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:549)
04-05 22:23:39.092: W/System.err(31845):    at nl.wacsite.wacsitebeta.MainFragmentTab$getListAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainFragmentTab.java:62)
04-05 22:23:39.092: W/System.err(31845):    at nl.wacsite.wacsitebeta.MainFragmentTab$getListAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainFragmentTab.java:1)
04-05 22:23:39.092: W/System.err(31845):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-05 22:23:39.092: W/System.err(31845):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-05 22:23:39.092: W/System.err(31845):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-05 22:23:39.092: W/System.err(31845):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-05 22:23:39.092: W/System.err(31845):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-05 22:23:39.092: W/System.err(31845):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
```

My question is: what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `jarr.length()` includes nulls, you sure there is no nulls in that array? can you try printing the length of that array?

Comment: Try debugging it and putting a breakpoint right after `json` is initialized. You should be able to view it's contents. If it doesn't look like items is in it, then there is something wrong with your original json string or the method of parsing.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen in the getter function of `JSONObject`. It means that you are trying to retrieve the value from the `JSONObject` using an id that doesn't actually exist. Before retrieving any value, check if that exist in the `JSONObject` by making use of `has(name)`. You can [check this](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) out for more details.

Hope this helps.